# Dictionary Output as String in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Looking at the print statements in the following format, it's also required to include any new countries and population entered as input. I can make the code to show an appended dictionary in a `dict` format but having a hard time showing in the following format. What am I doing incorrectly?

> Expected Output:
>
> ```
>    Vatican has Population 800
>    Vatican has Population 10200
>    ...
> ```

```
def main():
        countryPop = {'Vatican': 800, 'Tuvalu': 10200, 'Nauru': 11000, 'Palau': 17900,
                      'San Marino': 33420, 'Monaco': 38300, 'Marshall Islands': 55500}

        # while loop to repeat the input request and population display until 0 is entered
        while True:
            ctry = input('Enter country:')
            population = countryPop.get(ctry)
            print('Population:',population)
            if ctry == '0':
                break

            # Else if Loop meant to activate if a country unknown to the original dictionary is entered
            elif ctry not in countryPop:
                popIn = input("Country Pop:")
                countryPop[ctry] = popIn

        # printing the new list after breaking from the loop
        for ctry in countryPop:
            print(str(ctry)+" has population "+str(popIn))
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: replace `str(popIn)`with `countryPop.get(ctry)` in the last print statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `for key in dict` syntax to iterate over a dictionary's keys. Then, inside your loop, you can use `dict[key]` to read what's saved in that key. So the following would work:

```
countryPop = {'Vatican': 800, 'Tuvalu': 10200, 'Nauru': 11000, 'Palau': 17900,
                      'San Marino': 33420, 'Monaco': 38300, 'Marshall Islands': 55500}

for key in countryPop:
    print(key + " has Population " + str(countryPop[key]))
```

Output:

> Palau has Population 17900
>
> Tuvalu has Population 10200
>
> Vatican has Population 800
>
> San Marino has Population 33420
>
> Marshall Islands has Population 55500
>
> Monaco has Population 38300
>
> Nauru has Population 11000

Comment: You may want to read about the others available `dict` methods - like `dict.items()` for example.

Answer (score 2):

This will print what you want

```
for ctry, pop in countryPop.items():
    print(f"{ctry} has population {pop}")
```